# exim like rabbitmq for sending 200 emails per second

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, scale, exim, exim4

I'm trying to achieve 200 emails per second.
Which is 0.7 million emails in one hour.

While researching I found, If I render emails and handover 720 000 emails to exim before my scheduled emails sending time.

Then exim not having any other work. It will concentrate only on delivering emails.

Is there any way(hack) to achieve multiple queues in exim and I can trigger release the emails

Comment: "Lac" is a regionalism which isn't generally understood outside of the Indian cultural sphere.

Comment: Your bottleneck is probably your network bandwidth, not Exim or generally anything on the CPU. Even if you have gigabit speeds to all your destinations, having more than 50,000 concurrent TCP sessions isn't architecturally feasible.

Comment: Not a programming question; voting to close as off-topic for Stack Overflow.